# Connect web app to mysql database

Tags: android, mysql, ios, database, web-applications

I have a web application on Android and iOS which uses html and javascript for the project. I now have local values and app works fine. now I want to use a mysql database for my inputs, are there any good tutorial or sample codes on how to do that.
I'll appreciate if you can help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: You need to choose a server-side language that you can interact with via AJAX.

Comment: Can you accept an appropriate answer please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose a language that will operate server side to manage the database of your web app, e.g. you could use PHP as a language and MYSQL as a database software (it's free and awesome), for examples you could use http://php.net/ and search how to use specific mysql commands in PHP, or use a framework like CodeIgniter which has built in functions for database management and you can view some of them here https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html, but make sure you use the whole user guide on how to use it and how to set up your database configuration properly!

EDIT. If you don't want to use PHP for the actual app then you can use it server side, i.e. use it as part of a server file which connect to database, handle data, send it back, then send it back to your remote app where you can handle it with Javascript.

Comment: I know but you can't use php file in a mobile app

Comment: Yes you can. http://files.zend.com/help/Flash-Builder-for-PHP/Getting-Started/Mobile/build_a_mobile_%28php%29_application.htm

If this link goes out of date it is just a link to a tutorial for building your first php and mobile app to show the questioner that you can indeed use php, php html and javascript are all compatible.

Comment: http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/04/tiphp-tipython/ - just showing another software that used php and java.

Answer (score 1):

For web app and mysql communication need a scripting language like php and for database you need a database like mysql there is simple tutorial fo mysql connectivity 
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/12/android-populating-spinner-data-from-mysql-database/

Comment: The link you provided uses native code which makes it easy to manage databases. my mobile app uses html and javascript and I want to use those to connect to my database

Comment: You really shouldn't use javascript for connecting to a database if you want this app to be anyones but yours (then it's your own fault if everything messes up) Client javascript should be used only for the interfaces. It has security issues and all sorts, it's just bad practice.